# How/Is there a way to fix broken TASK links on Windows 7 for Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

**I solved this a while back by uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome but it didn't work the first attempt at this because I prematurely believed it failed**

---

I right-click on Google Chrome pinned to my taskbar and see this:

[image: Broken TASKS]

And then I select either New window or New incognito window and see this:

[image]

Is there a way to fix these links?

If so, how?

If not, would uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome work or put me back at the same problem?

**Please Explain Like I'm Five**

> **Backstory (Possibly Negligible to Answering Question)**
>
> A few hours ago, opening a new page with an already open Chrome would not load or even give an error page. It remained blank. Internet connection was good so I disconnected & reconnected with no change. So I closed Chrome, clicked the pinned Shortcut on Taskbar to reopen, and nothing would happen. I opened Firefox & downloaded a new Chrome (without deleting old) hoping to "refresh" things and believe the shortcuts would work out then. Not so lucky. But opening the file location of the desktop shortcut, I clicked on "new_chrome" which transformed into "old_chrome" (it just did) which opened successfully.
>
> The key shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> both worked but the taskbar shortcut still failed me. (In retrospect, I might've had better luck removing it & replacing it with the "old_chrome" application in that file location.)
>
> So thinking to put everything right again, I'd just uninstall Chrome. Did so (which removed both). But reinstalling gave an error that led to me doing a `chkdsk` to fix a corruption. With Google Chrome uninstalled & everything booting up normal, I reinstalled it. I can now click on the taskbar icon, the desktop icon, but these Tasks are broken. So now I'm here.

Comment: Try the following: 1. Right click Google icon in taskbar. 2. Right click on Google Chrome. 3. Click on Properties. 4. On the Shortcut tab, ensure target is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" and Start In is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application" (with quotes on both).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it as follows:

1. **Right-click** on the *Start* button and select **Properties**
2. On the *Start Menu* tab **check** the **Store and display recently opened items in the Start Menu and the taskbar** checkbox

   [image]
3. Click **OK** to save and close the window
4. Open the *Run* window (shortcut: <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and run the following command:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --enable-custom-jumplist
   ```

Mine worked after this. You can also go back and un-check the privacy box you checked on step 2 and it should still work.